# How to make the width to fit the text, and not be the full width with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

Here I have a title which I put into a row so it will take specific height. It is working, but the problem is that my `h1` is taking the whole row. I mean that I want the width of my text to be only as wide as the text is and not to be the same width with the parent row. Do you know any way how I can do this?

```html
    
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Survey Creato</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-r4NyP46KrjDleawBgD5tp8Y7UzmLA05oM1iAEQ17CSuDqnUK2+k9luXQOfXJCJ4I"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css"
    />
  </head>

  <body style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0)">
    <div style="height: 120px">
      <div class="w-100 h-50" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255)">
      </div>
      <div
        class="w-100 h-50 d-inline-block"
        style="background-color: rgb(134, 188, 37)"
      ></div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-5">
      <div
        id="survey"
        class="container justify-content-center"
        style="height: 600px; width: 1000px; background-color: white"
      >
        <div class="row">
          <h1
            class="display-4 mt-3 text-secondary text-center border"
            contenteditable="true"
          >
            Survey Name
          </h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed

```
     <div class="row">
              <h1
                class="display-4 mt-3 text-secondary text-center border"
                contenteditable="true"
              >
                Survey Name
              </h1>
     </div>
```

to

```
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
              <h1
                class="display-4 mt-3 text-secondary border"
                contenteditable="true"
                style="width: fit-content"
              >
                Survey Name
              </h1>
    </div>
```

Basically I added `justify-content-center` class to my row, and then `style="width: fit-content"` to my header.

Answer (score 2):

I think using `width: fit-content` should do the trick

```
h1 {
    width: fit-content;
}
```

Comment: it does, but when I do it, my text is no longer in the middle of the page, it goes in the left side. How do I fix that?

Comment: I fixed it, I added `justify-content-center` as a class in my row and now its okay